# CMB2 custom repeatable field missing data, how to fix?

Tags: php, wordpress, cmb2

I have a custom cmb2 field called as pb_info, which is consist of 4 different field abbreviation (select), course code(text), pe point( number), pe hour (number). and i want to use it inside a repeatable group as a group field. my code is work fine until i am inserting 2 rows of data, but it miss after 2nd row that means from 3rd row it missing data. and when i inspect it i saw from 3rd row the id of input field is not changing.

Here is my code :

registering field behaviour :

```
 function cmb2_render_pb_info_field_callback( $field, $value, $object_id, $object_type, $field_type ) {
    $value = wp_parse_args( $value, array(
    'pb_abbreviation' => '',
    'pb_crs_cd' => '',
    'pe_pnt'  => '',
    'pe_hr'     => '',
    ) );

?>
<div class="alignleft"><p><label for="<?php echo $field_type->_id( '_pb_abbreviation' ); ?>'">PB Abbreviation</label></p>
    <?php 
        echo $field_type->select( array(
        'name'    => $field_type->_name( '[pb_abbreviation]' ),
        'id'      => $field_type->_id( '_pb_abbreviation' ),
        'options' => cmb2_get_abbr_options( $value['pb_abbreviation'] ),
        'desc'    => '',

        ) ); 
    ?>
</div>
<div class="alignleft use_maxlength_validator"><p><label for="<?php echo $field_type->_id( '_pb_crs_cd' ); ?>'">PB Course Code</label></p>
    <?php echo $field_type->input( array(
        'class' => 'cmb_text_small',
        'name'  => $field_type->_name( '[pb_crs_cd]' ),
        'id'    => $field_type->_id( '_pb_crs_cd' ),
        'value' => $value['pb_crs_cd'],
        'maxlength' => 20,
        'desc'  => '',
    ) ); ?>
</div>
<div class="alignleft pb_credit"><p><label for="<?php echo $field_type->_id( '_pe_pnt' ); ?>'">PE Point</label></p>
    <?php echo $field_type->input( array(
        'class' => 'cmb_text_small',
        'name'  => $field_type->_name( '[pe_pnt]' ),
        'id'    => $field_type->_id( '_pe_pnt' ),
        'value' => $value['pe_pnt'],
        'desc'  => '',
    ) ); ?>
</div>
<div class="alignleft pb_hour"><p><label for="<?php echo $field_type->_id( '_pe_hr' ); ?>'">PE Hour</label></p>
    <?php echo $field_type->input( array(
        'class' => 'cmb_text_small',
        'name'  => $field_type->_name( '[pe_hr]' ),
        'id'    => $field_type->_id( '_pe_hr' ),
        'value' => $value['pe_hr'],
        'desc'  => '',
    ) ); ?>
</div>
<br class="clear">
<?php
    echo $field_type->_desc( true );

}
add_filter( 'cmb2_render_pb_info', 'cmb2_render_pb_info_field_callback', 10, 5 );
add_filter( 'cmb2_sanitize_pb_info', 'maybe_save_split_pb_values', 12, 4 );
/**
    * The following snippets are required for allowing the pb_info field
    * to work as a repeatable field, or in a repeatable group
*/
add_filter( 'cmb2_sanitize_pb_info','pb_sanitize', 10, 5 );
add_filter( 'cmb2_types_esc_pb_info', 'pb_escape', 10, 4 );


/**
    * Optionally save the Pb Info values into separate fields
*/

function pb_sanitize( $check, $meta_value, $object_id, $field_args, $sanitize_object ) {
    if ( ! is_array( $meta_value ) || ! $field_args['repeatable'] ) { return $check;  }
    foreach ( $meta_value as $key => $val ) {
        $meta_value[ $key ] = array_filter( array_map( 'sanitize_text_field', $val ) );
    }
    return array_filter($meta_value);
}

function maybe_save_split_pb_values( $override_value, $value, $object_id, $field_args ) {

    foreach ($override_value as $key => $data) {
        if($data['pb_crs_cd'] == '' && $data['pe_hr'] == '' && $data['pe_pnt'] == '' ){
            unset($override_value[$key]);
        }
    }
    if ( ! isset( $field_args['split_values'] ) || ! $field_args['split_values'] ) {
        // Don't do the override
        return $override_value;
    }
    foreach ($value as $key => $data) {
        if($data['pb_crs_cd'] == '' && $data['pe_hr'] == '' && $data['pe_pnt'] == '' ){
            unset($value[$key]);
        }
    }
    $pb_info_keys = array( 'pb_abbreviation', 'pb_crs_cd', 'pe_pnt', 'pe_hr' );
    foreach ( $pb_info_keys as $key ) {
        if ( ! empty( $value[ $key ] ) ) {
            update_post_meta( $object_id, $field_args['id'] . 'addr_'. $key, sanitize_text_field( $value[ $key ] ) );
        }
    }
    remove_filter( 'cmb2_sanitize__pb_info', 'pb_sanitize', 10, 5 );
    return true;
}

function pb_escape( $check, $meta_value, $field_args, $field_object ) {
    if ( ! is_array( $meta_value ) || ! $field_args['repeatable'] ) { return $check;  }
    foreach ( $meta_value as $key => $val ) { $meta_value[ $key ] = array_filter( array_map( 'esc_attr', $val ) );  }
    return array_filter($meta_value);
}

function cmb2_get_abbr_options( $value = false ) {
    $terms = get_terms( 'professional-body', array( 'hide_empty' => false, ) );
    $pb_abbreviation = '';
    $meta_key = "abbreviation";
    foreach ( $terms  as $term ) {
        $pb_abbreviation .= '<option value="'.  $term->term_id .'" '. selected( $value, $term->term_id, false ) .'>'. get_pb_meta( $term->term_id, $meta_key) .'</option>';
    }
    return $pb_abbreviation;
}
```

And the field initialization is:

```
$lu = new_cmb2_box( array(
    'id' => $prefix.'mcptr{#}',
    'title' => _('Round Informations'),
    'object_types' => array('mcpt'),
    'context'       => 'normal',
    'priority'      => 'high',
    'show_names'    => true,
    ));
    $group_field_id = $lu->add_field( array(
    'id'          => $prefix.'mcptre',
    'class'       => $prefix.'mcptgrp',
    'type'        => 'group',
    'repeatable'  => true, 
    'options'     => array(
    'group_title'   => __( 'Rounds {#}', 'cmb2' ),
    'closed'     => false,
    'add_button'    => __( 'Another Round', 'cmb2' ),
    'remove_button' => __( 'Remove Round', 'cmb2' ),
    'sortable'      => true,
    ),
    ) );

   $lu->add_group_field( $group_field_id, array(
    'name'             => 'PB Info',
    'id'               => $prefix.'pb_info_field',
    'type'              => 'pb_info',
    'repeatable'       => true,
    'classes' => 'pb_lu_info'
    ) );
```

So how can i fix the problem, i have never mention to do something special at row number 2 or 3, but somehow it take 2 rows of value and after 3rd row it stops changing id.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What i found is in cmb2.js file at 502 number line inside the addAjaxRow function the emptyrow iterator is not updating after clone it. but do not know why, as the default repeatable field working fine.

Comment: Have you found a solution to this, as it seems to be a bug with CMB2

Comment: Actually i have fixed that manually....